# Spring kafka consumer stops receiving message

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a spring microservice using kafka.

Here are consumer 5 config properties :

```
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG -> <ip>:9092
KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> StringDeserializer.class
VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> StringDeserializer.class
GROUP_ID_CONFIG -> "Group1"
MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG -> Integer.INT_MAX
```

It has been observed that when microservice is restarted , then kafka consumer stops receiving messages. Please help me in this.

Comment: Do you think it is possible for a third person to tell you where the problem is just looking at those 5 properties?

Comment: need more detailed information this info is not sufficient

Answer (score 0):

I believe your max.poll.interval.ms is the issue. It is set to 24days!! This represents the time the consumer is given to process the message. The the broker will hang for that long when the processing thread dies! Try setting it to a smaller value than Integer.INT_MAX, for example 30 seconds 30000ms.